# Como impedir que uma classe seja instanciada em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes-abstratas

Eu tenho uma classe mãe e quero herdá-la para uma classe filha. Porém a classe mãe não pode ser instanciada, apenas herdada. Em outras palavras, a classe mãe deve ser abstrata.

Apesar da POO do Python não ter suporte para abstração (ainda), existe um módulo da biblioteca padrão chamado `abc` — que possui a classe `ABC` e a função `abstractmethod`, para ser usado como um *decorator* para os métodos de classes que herdam de `ABC`.

Utilizando o decorador `abstractmethod` em um dos métodos da classe, a mesma se torna abstrata. Porém, minha classe mãe **não deve ter métodos abstratos**. Ela apenas deve ser abstrata.

O problema é que se eu não declarar algum dos métodos como abstrato, ela ainda pode ser instanciada. Veja o código abaixo que exemplifica o que estou dizendo:

```
class Mother(ABC):
    def method(self): pass

class AbstractMother(ABC):
    @abstractmethod        # Não quero que esse método seja abstrato!
    def method(self): pass

obj = Mother()          # Compila, damn it...
obj2 = AbstractMother() # Não compila (como esperado)
```

Uma possível solução então para o problema seria lançar uma exceção no método `__new__` ou no `__init__`, para que desse erro sempre que alguém tentasse instanciar diretamente da classe.

```
class Mother():
    def __init__(self): raise TypeError
    def method(self): pass

class Daughter(Mother):
    def __init__(self): pass

Daughter() # Compila
Mother()   # Não compilar, finalmente!
```

Porém essa seria uma solução "porca", já que todas as classes que herdarem serão obrigadas a sobrescreverem o método `__new__` ou o construtor, como no código acima.

Dito isso, minha dúvida é: em Python 3, como impedir que uma classe seja instanciada, sem obrigar que a classe filha sobrescreva algum método?

Comment: *"O problema é que se eu não declarar algum dos métodos como abstrato, ela ainda pode ser instanciada"* mas quer que uma classe não possa ser instanciada, ou ela é abstract ou static, se for abstract e não tiver algum método abstract é uma classe "sem código" :) se não quer tem uma instancia, use uma classe static então

Comment: Vou causar polêmica aqui e só porque vou usar o termo usado na pergunta. Vou comentar mesmo que desagrade algumas pessoas apaixonadas por certas tecnologias. Se quer uma solução não "porca" use uma linguagem não "porca". Explico. Não estou falando mal de Python. Algumas pessoas sabem que já usei Python no passado, eu incentivava as pessoas usarem para fazer *scripts* e ninguém me ouvia. Hoje as pessoas usam a linguagem para tudo e ninguém me ouve que não é para abusar dela. As pessoas vão pela moda, não porque tem uma pessoa falando.

Comment: Moda é usar sem pensar no que está fazendo, usa porque outros estão usando. não é algo passageiro como alguns acham. Python é uma boa linguagem para fazer coisas simples. Python pode ser usada para coisas mais complexas. Isso não quer dizer que ela é adequada para isso. Então em certos cenários ela é a ferramenta errada para a tarefa. Python não é uma linguagem de contratos, não foi feita para dar muitas garantias em tempo de compilação, ela tenta fazer o que for possível em tempo de execução.

Comment: Então já conside-se no lucro não compilar quando tem algo abstrato dentro da classe. Mas a linguagem não fornece uma forma de ter uma classe abstrata sem um método abstrato. O que faz sentido para uma linguagem que não deseja ter contratos fortes. È verdade que também não faz sentido ter para o método, portanto é inconsistente. Portanto a forma que a linguagem deixou você fazer é porca mesmo, não tem jeito. Se quer algo limpo então precisa fazer em uma linguagem que garanta contratos o tempo todo (o que é raro, mas para ese caso tem). Ou aceite a deficiência da linguagem e use o "porco".

Comment: Acho que a pergunta não chamou a linguagem de "porca", mas tudo bem, pode ser um problema de interpretação de texto de um de nós dois.

Comment: @jsbueno sim, parece que você está interpretando meu texto errado para atender o seu interesse, como costuma fazer sempre. Não pode falar que Python não é para todas tarefas que você aparece querendo santificar a linguagem. Interpretando meu texto para você: "se quer uma solução limpa, use uma linguagem que ofereça isso, se quer uma solução não ideal aceite que a linguagem escolhida não é ideal e seja feliz".

Comment: Nem a pergunta chama a linguagem de porca e nem o comentário fala isso. Me parece que é o "problema" de sempre, falar que Python não é solução para todos os problemas do universo. Dizem que isso pode incomodar algumas pessoas, mesmo que seja verdade.

Comment: Caro @Maniero concordo com sua visão sobre Python, mas essa thread aqui nos comments está desnecessária (inclusive esse comment meu é desnecessário). Dê uma relida no help desse site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @RafaelOdon concordo com você mas como eu participei dela se eu apagar vão me acusar de estar querendo esconder o conteúdo., como já foi feito antes, com sua sinalização acho que outros poderão fazer algo. Só um detalhe: os primeiros comentários que eu fiz são pertinentes à pergunta e acrescentam informação importante, e não devem ser apagados já que seguem o que determina o link que você postou, o resto é só reclamação porque a pessoa não gostou dos comentários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi direito, o que você procura é definir a funcionalidade do método `__init__` (ou algum outro método qualquer) na classe `Mother`, mas quer que apenas a classe `Daughter` possa ser de fato instanciada. Ou seja, "aproveitar" o código de `Mother` para as subclasses, mas deixá-la como uma classe "abstrata soft".

Uma forma de fazer isso é checar a própria classe do objeto sendo criado dentro do `__init__` e apenas produzir o erro caso a classe seja `Mother`:

```
class Mother:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        if self.__class__ is Mother:
            raise TypeError("Mother class cannot be instantiated")
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class Daughter(Mother):
    pass

Daughter(1, 2, 3)  # funciona
Mother(1, 2, 3)  # produz um TypeError
```

Embora de um ponto de vista mais teórico, eu concorde com o comentário de que não faz muito sentido ter uma classe que é tratada como se possuísse um método abstrato, mas que está definido dentro dela.

Comment: isso funciona. é um caso em que é melhor comparar com "is" que com "==".

Comment: bem observado @jsbueno, editei meu exemplo.

Answer (score 5):

Se por algum motivo não quiser colocar uma comparação simples no `__init__` como está na [resposta do @jfaccioni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513557/500) , dá para criar um método `__init_subclass__` na classe de base que sobre-escreva um método abstrato criado só para impedir o instanciamento. (e usar os mecanismos dos abcs)

O `__init_subclass__` é um método de classe especial que é chamado sempre que uma subclasse é criada.

```py
import abc
class Base(abc.ABC):
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _sentinel(self): pass
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        # Injeta um método só para sobre-escrever o abstract-method:
        cls._sentinel = lambda self: None

class B(Base): pass
```

No modo interativo:

```py
In [10]: b = B()                                                                                                                                                                             

In [11]: a = Base()                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-befb5e64d15f> in <module>
----> 1 a = Base()

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Base with abstract method _sentinel
```